# Ошибка сервера

Tags: php, mysql

```
if(!@mysql_connect('localhost', 'user1734_modal', '325500100105a')) {
 echo 'Не удалось соединиться с сервером. Попробуйте позднее.';
 exit;
} else {
 $database_name = 'user1734_monty';
 mysql_select_db($database_name);
}
```

В чём проблема? Хром выдаёт следующее:

```
Ошибка сервера

На веб-сайте произошла ошибка при получении http://site.ru/. Веб-сайт может быть закрыт на обслуживание или настроен неправильно.

Вот несколько советов и рекомендаций:
Обновите эту страницу позже.

Ошибка HTTP 500 (Internal Server Error): При попытке сервера выполнить запрос возникла неожиданная ситуация.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

нужно включить показ ошибок 
в .htaccess прописать php_flag display_errors 1

Answer (score 2):

Рекомендую пользоваться дэбаггером. Пройдитесь по скрипту с самого начала дэбаггером и посмотрите на какой строке скрипт падает.

Answer (score 2):

Если это весь код, который там выполняется, тогда у вас указана неправильно имя базы данных(user1734_monty).

P.S. смотрите error.log, там должна лежать ошибка.

Comment: с чего вы решили, что не правильно? у разных хостеров поразному это все.

Answer (score 1):

в корней сайта есть .htaccess файл? попробуйте его удалить/переименовать

либо у хостинга какието проблемы, возможно криво настроено.